# I'm trying to create my portfolio with Nuxt JS & the Wordpress REST API

Tags: wordpress, rest, nuxt.js

I'm currently trying to create my portfolio with Nuxt JS & the Wordpress REST API, however I'm having problems when I try to create the single posts, on refreshing the single post page the data is lost and Nuxt.js gives me an error.

I have tried many tutorials to try to set up my portfolio with Nuxt.js and Wordpress REST API but each time nobody explains the solution to the problem when refreshing the page.

Comment: Your question is not a correct one. We need the code. How do you fetch the posts? how are you showing it? We need to see the way you are coding.

Comment: Here is the tutorial I followed to the letter: https://yossiabramov.com/blog/nuxt-js-and-the-wordpress-rest-api

I don't know how to create a "Nuxt-Link" to a single post that doesn't lose data on page refresh.

Comment: Voting for a close because as wrote above, we need some code, a [repro] or anything showing some minimal effort regarding the given question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.